# Change result of an array if it's blank

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-opengraph, fetch

I'm using OpenGraph to parse some meta property datas from websites, like this:

```
$v = 'http://url.com/';
$graph = OpenGraph::fetch($v);
$image = $graph->image . "\n";
$title = $graph->title . "\n";
$site_name = $graph->site_name . "\n";
$description = $graph->description . "\n";
```

But, some websites don't have the meta property og:image on it.. So my $image array become an empty array and result in something like this:

```
<img src="" />
```

How can I change the array value for a generic value if $image array is empty? That's seems simple but I can't find a good solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can solve your doubts ? :

```
$image = $graph->image != "" ? $graph->image."\n" : "default_value"."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to handle it yourself by testing the return value:

```
$graph = OpenGraph::fetch($v);
$image = $graph->image;
if (empty($image))
{
    $image = 'http://yoursite.com/default_og_img.jpg';
}
```